# My code is not showing database values in front end. can anyone help me?

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have tried to display the name of my database table with id but it is not working. Can anyone help me where is the problem?
It says successfully added data in category but above code is not working to display in table.

**CODE**:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
    <th>Sr No.</th>
    <th>Category Name</th>
    </tr>
    <? php 
        global $connectiondb;
        $ViewQuery="SELECT * FROM category";
        $Execute=mysqli_query($connection, $ViewQuery);
        $SrNo=0;
        while ($DataRows=mysqli_fetch_array($Execute,MYSQLI_BOTH);) {
            $Id=$DataRows["id"];
            $CategoryName=$DataRows["name"];
            $SrNo++;
        ?>
    <tr>
        <td><? php echo $Id; ?></td>
        <td><? php echo $CategoryName; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <? php } ?>
```

Comment: Remove the ; inside the while loop condition.

Comment: And change to <?php

Comment: your code has `<? php` instead of `<?php`, a space makes lot of difference.

Comment: 'Not working' is not very helpful.  How is it not working?

Comment: To help you debug your PHP codes, put these at the top of your codes.

`<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?>
`

Answer (score 0):

Try to display SrNo view has larger than 0 or not. If SrNo is greater than 0 mean means data to display. 
Please try this code of me see it help for you or not:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>Sr No.</th>
        <th>Category Name</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
   global $connectiondb;
        $ViewQuery="SELECT * FROM category";
        $Execute=mysqli_query($connection, $ViewQuery);
        $SrNo=0;
    while($DataRows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($Execute)) {
        $Id=$DataRows["id"];
        $CategoryName=$DataRows["name"];
        $SrNo++;
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $Id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $CategoryName; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```